# WordPress Nav Walker - Multilevel issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make the multilevel icon to make it like the right icon or something. I'm using the bootstrap navwalker.

This is my current menu btw (html converted to wp menu): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYeJw.png)

***Edit: Sorry I forgot to add my existing code.***

In my header.php I have this:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             =>  3,
                    'container'         => '<div>',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav-link scrollto',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
          ) );
          ?>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Deep Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="getstarted scrollto" href="#about">Get Started</a></li>

        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav>
```

In my functions.php I just registered the navigation walker of bootstrap

```
function register_navwalker(){
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );
```

and... This is what I'm trying to achieve: [screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soGwB.png)

Comment: It is better if you shared your code with us so, we will check and trying to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding code but i have seen that you have include navwalker class file in in register_navwalker function.
can you please share the class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php ? so, it is better to solve the issue.